# How to remove extra spaces from all leaf nodes of an arbitrary structure

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

The code below seems to traverse the structure fine but when it returns from travrse_it the structure that was passed is in not modified. The leafs are immutable so I assume I need to return it. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here:

```
r = ['crossABC', ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['r       n   w   ', 'r       n   r   ', 'r       n   n ', 'n      w           w   ', 'n      w           r ', 'n      w      n', 'n      r    w   ', 'n      r    r  ', 'n      r    n  ', 'n      n   w   ', 'n      n   r ', 'n      n   n  ']]

rm_space = lambda x: re.sub('\s+', ' ', x)

def traverse_it(it, str_func):
  if (isinstance(it, list)):
    for item in it:
      traverse_it(item, str_func)
  elif (isinstance(it, dict)):
    for key in it.keys():
      traverse_it(it[key], str_func)
  elif ( isinstance(it, basestring) ):
    return str_func(it)
  else:
    print "Cant travers unkown item"

traverse_it(r,rm_space)
```

The expected output:

```
r = ['crossABC', ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['r n w ', 'r n r ', 'r n n ', 'n w w ', 'n w r ', 'n w n', 'n r w ', 'n r r ', 'n r n ', 'n n w ', 'n n r ', 'n n n ']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply returing value does not affect the items. You need to assign the return value back. The code also need to return for `list`, `dict` type.

```
def traverse_it(it, str_func):
    if isinstance(it, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(it):
            it[i] = traverse_it(item, str_func)
        return it
    elif isinstance(it, dict):
        for key in it:
            it[key] = traverse_it(it[key], str_func)
        return it
    elif isinstance(it, basestring):
        return str_func(it)
    else:
        print "Cant travers unkown item"
```